# Changed SA Password in Kitematic (Docker for Mac), I have lost all databases in localhost

Tags: docker, kitematic

I have changed the SA Password in Kitematic (Docker for Mac). When I logged back into Azure Data Studio I discovered that all my databases had gone.

Are the databases lost forever every time SA Password is changed whether in Kitematic or via Terminal command?

Thank you for your support and answer to this query.

Best, A.